# How to change one attribute in params require?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I want to create a todo with title and user_id.But i dont want my request body contain user_id.I want to encode token from header and take an id of user from encoded token and after that past in this expression `params.require(:todo).permit(:title, :finished, :user_id)` instead of `:user_id`.

How can i accomplish that?

I am using rails 5.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could manually assign the value using `merge` method for example

```
params.require(:todo).permit(:title, :finished, :user_id).merge(user_id: 'value from encode token')
```